# Previous function is called/Event listener 'delayed' by one

Tags: actionscript-3

I have altered an image carousel I downloaded, to rotate to the next picture (left or right) when I click one of the two buttons I added. The original carousel was built to rotate according to mouse movement/position.

For some reason, whenever I click the 'right' or 'left' button, which each rotate the carousel in their respecive directions, **the event listener/handler is one 'behind'. It does whatever it should've done the previous time I clicked a button.** To put it more clearly, the first button click it does nothing. The second button click it responds to what I clicked the last time.

Example:

- I click the left button, nothing happens.
- Then I click the right button, the carousel rotates to the left (because I clicked the left button before this click)
- Then I click the left button, the carousel rotates to the right (idem).

See the code below. It seems fairly simple; no complex structure or whatever.

You can ignore most vars and positioning (like `focalLength`,`vanishingPointX`,`radius`, etc), I suppose. I'm guessing this bug is either related to the importing/processing of the XML, the `for()` loops, or the structure the .as file has.

```
package  {
        //here are all the imports 

        public class Imagereel extends Sprite {
            var imgurl:URLRequest = new URLRequest()
            var loadedimgs:uint = 0;
            var images_num = 0;
            var imageHolders:Array = new Array();
            var imageHolder:MovieClip;
            var btnLeft:BtnLeft = new BtnLeft;
            var btnRight:BtnRight = new BtnRight;

        //Set the focal length
        var focalLength:Number = 2000;

        //Set the vanishing point
        var vanishingPointX:Number = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        var vanishingPointY:Number = stage.stageHeight / 2;

        //The 3D floor for the images
        var floor:Number = 40;

        //Radius of the circle
        var radius:Number = 350;

        //We use 70x70 sized images (change this if different for your images)
        const IMAGE_WIDTH:uint = 393;
        const IMAGE_HEIGHT:uint = 249;

        var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        var xmlData:XML = new XML();        

        public function Imagereel() {
            //here's the positioning of the buttons
            //here are the button addChilds

            xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("carousel.xml"));
            xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);
            btnLeft.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, prevImg);
            btnRight.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextImg);

        }
        function LoadXML(e:Event):void {
            xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
            Parseimage(xmlData);
        }
        function Parseimage(imageinput:XML):void {
            var imageurl:XMLList = imageinput.image.iurl;

            images_num = imageurl.length();
            for (var i:int = 0; i < images_num; i++) {
                var urlElement:XML = imageurl[i];

                imageHolder = new MovieClip();
                var imageLoader = new Loader();
                imageHolder.addChild(imageLoader);
                imageHolder.mouseChildren = false;
                imageLoader.x = - (IMAGE_WIDTH);
                imageLoader.y = - (IMAGE_HEIGHT);
                imageHolders.push(imageHolder);
                imgurl.url = imageurl[i];
                imageLoader.load(imgurl);
                imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
            }
        }
        function imageLoaded(e:Event) {
            //Update the number of loaded images
            loadedimgs++;

            //Check to see if this is the last image loaded
            if (loadedimgs == images_num) {
                //Set up the carousel
                initializeCarousel();
            }
        }
        function initializeCarousel() {
            //Calculate the angle difference between the images (in radians)
            var angleDifference:Number = Math.PI * (360 / images_num) / 180;

            //Loop through the images
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < imageHolders.length; i++) {
                //Assign the imageHolder to a local variable
                var imageHolder:MovieClip = (MovieClip)(imageHolders[i]);

                //Get the angle for the image (we space the images evenly)
                var startingAngle:Number = angleDifference * i -0.30;

                //Position the imageHolder
                imageHolder.xpos3D = radius * Math.cos(startingAngle);
                imageHolder.zpos3D = radius * Math.sin(startingAngle);
                imageHolder.ypos3D = floor;

                //Set a "currentAngle" attribute for the imageHolder
                imageHolder.currentAngle = startingAngle;
                var scaleRatio = focalLength/(focalLength + imageHolder.zpos3D);

                //Position the imageHolder to the stage (from 3D to 2D coordinates)
                imageHolder.x = vanishingPointX + imageHolder.xpos3D * scaleRatio;
                imageHolder.y = vanishingPointY + imageHolder.ypos3D * scaleRatio;

                //Add the imageHolder to the stage
                addChild(imageHolder);
            }
            sortZ();
        }

        function prevImg(e:MouseEvent) {
            //Loop through the images
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < imageHolders.length; i++) {
                var imageHolder:MovieClip = (MovieClip)(imageHolders[i]);
                //Set a new 3D position for the imageHolder
                imageHolder.xpos3D = radius * Math.cos(imageHolder.currentAngle);
                imageHolder.zpos3D = radius * Math.sin(imageHolder.currentAngle);
                var scaleRatio;

                //Calculate a scale ratio
                scaleRatio = focalLength/(focalLength + imageHolder.zpos3D);

                //Update the imageHolder's coordinates
                imageHolder.x = vanishingPointX+imageHolder.xpos3D * scaleRatio;
                imageHolder.y = vanishingPointY+imageHolder.ypos3D * scaleRatio;

                //spinning the carousel
                imageHolder.currentAngle += 0.6285;
            }   
            //Call the function that sorts the images so they overlap each others correctly
            sortZ();
        }
        function nextImg(e:MouseEvent) {
            //Loop through the images
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < imageHolders.length; i++) {
                var imageHolder:MovieClip = (MovieClip)(imageHolders[i]);
                //Set a new 3D position for the imageHolder
                imageHolder.xpos3D = radius * Math.cos(imageHolder.currentAngle);
                imageHolder.zpos3D = radius * Math.sin(imageHolder.currentAngle);
                var scaleRatio;

                //Update the imageHolder's coordinates
                imageHolder.x = vanishingPointX+imageHolder.xpos3D * scaleRatio;
                imageHolder.y = vanishingPointY+imageHolder.ypos3D * scaleRatio;

                //spinning the carousel
                imageHolder.currentAngle -= 0.6285;
            }
            sortZ();
        }
        //This function sorts the images so they overlap each others correctly
        function sortZ():void {
            imageHolders.sortOn("zpos3D", Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING);

            //Set new child indexes for the images
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < imageHolders.length; i++) {
                setChildIndex(imageHolders[i], i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So what this code does:

1. `carousel.xml` is imported
2. The xml is processed so that the image paths there are converted to displayed images
3. A carousel is made out of the images
4. The sortZ() function makes sure that the images are aligned in 3D perspective properly; just like `z-index` in CSS would do.
5. When clicking `btnLeft` or `btnRight`, the carousel rotates to the left or right (this is done by updating the value of `imageHolder.currentAngle`).

When I put `trace`'s inside the prevImg() and nextImg() functions, I do see the trace that 
belongs to the right function, and not the previously clicked one. So it seems that Flash *does* call the right event.

So how do I get rid of this bug?
Help and tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: sounds like a doozy, would do some more tracing and just drop in some breakpoints and step through the code a few times to see if anything becomes apparent (check that all variables appear to be set "correctly" for a simple test case)

Comment: Thanks for the edit @shaunhusain, this looks much better :D

Comment: With 'breakpoints', do you mean debugging? I don't know much about how this works, but when trying some stuff I can't find anything. Also, what do you mean by 'variables set correctly'?

Comment: Yup with breakpoints I meant clicking/double clicking the line number in the editor so it marks the execution of code to stop when it hits the code corresponding to that line.  By set correctly, I meant make sure that as you step through line by line (F6 on my computer) you can look at the watch/variables box and make sure it looks like all the variables are being set to the correct values.  Looks like there's a more direct answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The answer below provided the solution for me, so I'm all happy now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `imageHolder.currentAngle` assignment (the line where you change it) BEFORE the code that alters imageHolder's 3D position.

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < imageHolders.length; i++) {
            var imageHolder:MovieClip = (MovieClip)(imageHolders[i]);
            //Set a new 3D position for the imageHolder
            imageHolder.currentAngle += 0.6285; // <== HERE
            imageHolder.xpos3D = radius * Math.cos(imageHolder.currentAngle);
            imageHolder.zpos3D = radius * Math.sin(imageHolder.currentAngle);
            var scaleRatio;

            //Calculate a scale ratio
            scaleRatio = focalLength/(focalLength + imageHolder.zpos3D);

            //Update the imageHolder's coordinates
            imageHolder.x = vanishingPointX+imageHolder.xpos3D * scaleRatio;
            imageHolder.y = vanishingPointY+imageHolder.ypos3D * scaleRatio;

            //spinning the carousel
        }
```

The same for the other function.

Comment: Yes that's it! Thanks! Could you also tell me why it does work now? Because I don't quite understand. It would seem to me that the `x`, `y` and `scaleRatio` are unrelated to `currentAngle`, or..?

Comment: Well, when you execute a turn, the thing you derive your coordinates from is the `currentAngle`. This means, if you want to rotate your carousel, you have to chenge that angle first, and then recalculate all dependant data. You did the reverse and wondered, how come the data only displays the previous state. And, they are related through `xpos3D` and `zpos3D` that are used in assignment of `x` and `y`.